# Установка Ruby и Ruby on Rails в Mac OS

Tags: macos, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Подскажите пожалуйста!!!  У меня стоит Mac и из коробки в нем стоит ruby 1.8.7. 
Как правильно установить установить rvm, обновить ruby и установить ror?  Я находил много вариантов установки но все они в процессе установки выдавали какую нибудь ошибку.

Comment: У меня все получилось, но совсем по другой инструкции (собирал из разных частей)

Homebrew

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"

Git
brew install git

Install RVM:
$ bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
$ source ~/.bash_profile
$ rvm requirements

Install ruby:
$ rvm install 1.9.3

Install Rails:
$ [sudo] gem install rails --version 3.2.13


rvm use ruby 1.9.2 --default

 После чего в терминале при запуске сервера (rails c) у меня попросил установить bundle

в терминале вводим bundle install

Answer (score 1):

Ставьте как в [этой инструкции](http://s7at1c.ru/rvm-ruby-1-9-2-rails3-on-macos.html). Будет ошибка - напишите после какого шага и какая именно.